# Ideals in $S^{-1}A$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, localization

I am studying localization of rings and got stuck at a problem. It states that if $S$ is a multiplicatively closed subset of a ring $A$  then fractional ideals of $\ S^{-1}A $ are in bijective correspondence with those of $A$ which do not meet $S$. However, prime ideals of $  S^{-1}A $ are in bijective correspondence with those of $A$ which do not meet $S$.

> My question is why can't we say that ideals of $A$  which do not meet $S$ are in bijective correspondence with those of $S^{-1}A$?

We know that ideals of $S ^{-1}A$ are of the form $S^{-1}I$ where $I$ is an ideal of $A$. Why won't the correspondence $I\rightarrow S^{-1}I $ work?

Comment: I don't get this: "fractional ideals of $\ S^{-1}A $ are in bijective correspondence with those of $A$ which do not meet $S$." Really?

Comment: i am sorry.The statement holds for Dedekind domain.

Answer (score 3):

The correspondence $I\mapsto S^{-1}I$ need not be injective.  For instance, let $A=k[x,y]$ and $S=\{y^n:y\in\mathbb{N}\}$.  Then if $I=(x)$ and $J=(xy)$, $S^{-1}I= S^{-1}J$ even though $I\neq J$ and neither intersects $S$.

Comment: could you please give intuition behind this.

Comment: Well, why would you expect $I\mapsto S^{-1}I$ to be injective to begin with?  I don't know what intuition you want that isn't provided by just seeing how the example works.  The surprising fact that you should perhaps want intuition for is the fact that it _is_ injective on prime ideals.

Comment: If you find it helpful to think about things geometrically, what's going on in $\operatorname{Spec} A$ is that it's possible to have closed sets $C$ and $D$ and an open set $U$ such that $C\cap U=D\cap U\neq \emptyset$ but $C\neq D$ (because, for instance, $C$ might contain points in the complement of $U$ that are not in $D$).